# Why python re module does not work with @?

Tags: python, regex

In the following example shows weird problem: Python pattern does not work.

```
import re
data = r'blah blah @Component blah blah'
m = re.match(r'\@Component', data)
print m
```

It would print out:

```
None
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: Given as the actual problem is in no way specific to `@`, perhaps the question's title should be changed so that it can better be found by folks to whom it's actually relevant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead, and `@` has no special meaning so you do not need to escape it.

```
>>> re.search(r'@Component', data).group()
'@Component'
```

Answer (score 3):

[`match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) tries to match the pattern at the beginning of the string. Use [`search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) instead. Also, `@` doesn't have any special meaning in Python's regex, so you don't need to escape it.

Working code:

```
>>> re.search('(@Component)', data).groups()
('@Component',)
```